# Run HP Mini 110-1125nr without fan?

Tags: laptop

I am removing the fan from the notebook listed above due to annoying fan noise. Will the computer boot with the fan unplugged? The tachometer of the fan is not sending any signals.

Comment: It might boot; But it likely will nearly instantly overheat and shutoff; You will want to replace the fan not remove it; removing the fan isn’t a solution

Comment: I did not remove the heatsink.

Comment: I never said anything about a heatsink. Just the heatsink isn’t enough to cool your COU; if it was then the OEM wouldn’t have used one.

Comment: @Ramhound If I remove the fan and leave the heatsink intact, will the computer do what you said?

Comment: John already answered your question; I also literally said it would more than likely overheat within moments

Comment: For people answering - According to https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/36331/intel-atom-processor-n270-512k-cache-1-60-ghz-533-mhz-fsb.html this ancient CPU has a paltry 2.5 watt tdp.

Comment: @Ramhound with a cooling pad will it still overheat?

Comment: @ssr215 - See my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

The laptop will probably not start because of a Fan Error. That is common.

Do NOT remove a laptop Fan as that will cause the CPU to overheat.

Comment: I did not remove the heat sink, however.

Comment: Indeed. I've known many laptops where even though the fan was working perfectly, the body would get hot enough to be uncomfortable on one's lap.

Comment: It will still overheat.  I have seen Fans quit before (bad Fans) and the laptop won't even run

Comment: @John is the heatsink enough for cooling the old laptop?

Comment: I do not think so.  I have laptops with failing fans and the fans needed to be replaced to get the laptop to start.

Comment: @John If it doesn't boot, can you think of a way to spoof the fan's signal?

Comment: I do not think you can spoof the fan, but I am not totally certain. For sure, removing the fan is not a good idea.

Comment: @ssr215 - **No** it’s not.

Comment: @John Do you have anything to support the claim that the CPU will overheat.  I have seen this kind of comment a few times, but I'm skeptical.  As is true of most intel CPU's this CPU has SpeedStep technology, so I would expect it to throttle right back to prevent itself from overheating.  I would expect it may lower the life expectency of the CPU a little, but as the CPU is way past end of life, so what?

Comment: I have had two computers with Fan errors and both shut down to prevent CPU damage.

Comment: @John are they the same processor as davidgo suggested?

Comment: My laptops were different machines.

Comment: What processor is it, and what year are they created?

Comment: ThinkPad machines - one was 8 or 9 years old. One was newer and still in warranty.

Comment: @John DO you have any HP machnes that do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121094/discussion-between-ssr215-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the CPU model. I don't know what is inside yours but I have two fanless tablet PC, one has Intel Cherry Trail Z8300 and other has Intel Apollo Lake Pentium N3450. They both going well without problem even I can play games.

The question has been changed so I add to the answer:

At first I thought your laptop wouldn't know if it has a fan connected. But unfortunately, yes, it doesn't work without a fan according to [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/HP-mini-110-3000-message-saying-cooler-fan-not-working/td-p/1065689).

Comment: Search up HP Mini 110-1125nr

Comment: @ssr215 - Instead of asking us to do research, that should be contained within your question.

Comment: A tablet without a fan was probably designed to run without a fan. A Laptop with a fan needs it running even at low speed for the regular laptops I have known.

Comment: Don't worry about the final shape, it's the processor that matters. The Cherry Trail doesn't even have a passive cooler. I have seen laptops with these CPU's which have fan too. But if I have to say like this logic, I would say don't play with the factory settings if you are not an expert.

Comment: @user30878, That is the Model 3000. I am talking about Model 1125nr.

Comment: I know, the main band is same.

Comment: @user30878, Those models have different fans.

Comment: 1- https://www.amazon.com/FixTek-HP-Mini-110-3000-CTO/dp/B06Y4YLCN6    2- https://www.amazon.com/Replacement-HP-Mini-110-1125NR-Laptop/dp/B0150ZPE6O